# ros_info float32[] c++

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and am trying to print part of LaserScan message, in particular the ranges bit. Is there a format identifier or some other nice way to print this float32 array out?

Thanks

ROS Hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198199/ros_info-float32%5B%5D-c++/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not the vector itself, but you can print the whole message with `ROS_INFO_STREAM`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1